# Toggle select options w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have selector with multiple option grouped into option groups. I am trying to toggle select/deselect of all options when an optgroup label is clicked.

It works fine on initial load, but I also have a functionality that allows me to copy options from one selector to another and back. Once options are copied my toggle stops working.

```
$("optgroup").toggle(function(){
    $(this).children().attr("selected", "selected");
}, function() {
    $(this).children().attr("selected", false);
});
```

Here's the [copy/remove script](http://jsfiddle.net/SwrVK/6/).

Comment: If you're using the latest version of jQuery, you should use the `prop` method. If you're using an older version of jQuery, use `removeAttr('selected')` instead of `attr('selected', false)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will **not** give you the desired UX, but it will solve the issue you are having with the toggle events getting unbinded: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/SwrVK/9/

```
$("select").delegate('optgroup', 'click', function() {
    $(this).toggle(function() {
        $(this).children().attr("selected", "selected");
    }, function() {
        $(this).children().attr("selected", false);
    });
});
```

You can either use .live() or .delegate(); the problem is they only work with base events like 'click' or 'hover', and not derived events like 'toggle' (which is why it was wrapped above).

Note that this solution solves the unbinding issue, but in terms of UX, a few more tweaks are required.

**Updated: UX additions** http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/SwrVK/15/

I think your intention is to select all the child options when a group is clicked.  The code below will do that.

```
$("select").delegate('optgroup', 'click', function() {
    $(this).children().attr("selected", "selected");
});
```

This chunk of code below will make it so that you can still select each child option independently.  Events propagate up the node tree, so you have to prevent it (in this case).

```
$("select").delegate('option', 'click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: It all looks right and makes perfect sense, but I have to click the first optgroup twice to select all children... I think $("optgroup").live("click", function() { is more streamlined, but the results aren't much better... weird...

Comment: Yep, this works great! But we lost the toggle to deselect is click optgroups with all options selected. I guess it'll need an additional look for each to see if they all are selected?..

Comment: Initially I added logic that would allow you to toggle the selected on and off, but that logic added more complexity with very little benefit.  The way the 'select' element works is that it automatically deselects all other objects as soon as a click occurs.  To implement this logic, you would have to catch that initial click.  If you wanted to implement a toggling effect, you would have to manage that default behavior.

Comment: Just realized the code does not work in IE... Any ideas what's the problem?

Comment: @santa: OptGroups in IE cannot have a click event; maybe ie9 does.  It's a pain, and the easiest workaround is to NOT use the html 'select' element at all. http://forum.jquery.com/topic/why-don-t-click-event-for-select-option-works-in-ie-8

Answer (score 3):

The problem has to do with the binding the toggle event.  As the optgroups move in and out of selects, the events are no longer attached to the newly created optgroups.  Sadly, there is no live binding for toggle events.  You can hack something together that will get the job done with something like:

```
$("optgroup").live("click", function() {
    var $children = $(this).children();
    if($children.attr("selected")) {
        $children.attr("selected", false);
    } else {
        $children.attr("selected", "selected");
    }
});
```

Do keep in mind, this will bind the click event to any optgroups ever created on the page and could have some unforeseen side effects.  I recommend using live with a class and not optgroup alone to mitigate this risk.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lw6QC/

Comment: +1 Beat me to it.  I had the same type of solution for the same reason here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Lf3L4/

Comment: Yeah, I saw yours as I posted mine.  You actually beat me to it.  I am glad I got the answer because I can now comment =D.

Comment: I actually still have problems even in these jsfiddle examples... Clicking on optgroups should toggle select/deselect for children of that optgroup. And it seem to work on and off...

Comment: It would be nice if you changed your user name to something we'd have a chance of remembering next our paths cross.

Comment: @santa - the issue is that mousedown changes the selection of the current option so the detect of what the previous state is on the click event is off.  I'm experimenting with how to fix.

Comment: Another approach that may work is to move the dom elements back and forth between the lists.  Instead of recreating the dom each time.  This way the listeners remain attached.  It would have to be reworked to listen for when the option's are clicked instead of the optgroups.